# Jupyter Import Module AND use function. How can I do that?

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-import

I need to import a function `classify(par1, par2, par3)`
from a module called `_Y03_Labeling`. Importing does work, but using its functions with more than one extra parameter doesnt work.

Question : How can I import functions with more than one Parameter?

.

What I already tried ( Without Success):

I successfully can run the whole notebook2 from notebook1 with the following code:

```
import _Y03_Labeling
Labeling =_Y03_Labeling
```

(Why I know if it is successful? Because its comments are printed out). Whenever I try to run:

```
X,y = classify(a,b,c)
```

I get the following error: "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

I tried many variations from the import line, including:

```
import _Y03_Labeling
Labeling =_Y03_Labeling
X,y = Labeling.classify(a,b,c)

#  or:

from _Y03_Labeling import classify 

#  or:

import _Y03_Labeling 
X,y = _Y03_Labeling .classify(a,b,c)
```

Sadly none of them worked for me.

Things i also did so far:

- shutting down the _Y03_Labeling notebook before I run the main Notebook
- putting the function in the second notebook into a class, importing the class from the notebook and calling the function. (works only if function needs 1 parameter)
- also i didnt forgot "self" i the function declaration with the class try.

I am glad, this forum exists and thankful for every possible help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Focus on the question, not background information.